# Elastic search 2.1 query to get only a element from an array

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have below mapping, I want to access a property of imageMap instead of all collection.

```
"imageMap": {
            "properties": {
              "item1": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "item2": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "item3": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
```

Below is the sample data

```
imageMap": [
      {
        "item1": 20893,
        "item2": "ImageThumbnail_100_By_44",
        "item3": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRg"
    },
    {
    "item1": 20893,
        "item2": "ImageThumbnail_400_By_244",
        "item3": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2w"
    }
    ]
```

Below is my Query that is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Updated:**

```
    {
      "_source": {
        "include": [
          "imageMap"
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
             "term": {
                "imageMap.item1": {
                "value": 20893
                }
              },
              "term": {
                "imageMap.item2": {
                  "value": "imagethumbnail_100_by_44"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Expected Result is below only single element of imageMap, but i am getting array :

```
"_source": {
          "imageMap": [
            {
              "item2": "ImageThumbnail_100_By_44",
              "item1": 20893,
              "item3": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: How does your query look like and can you give an example of what you expect to retrieve from the sample data you've shown above?

Comment: By "not working", do you mean that 1) you're not getting any results or 2) that you are getting wrong/unexpected results? Please make it clear, help us help you!

Comment: I was not getting data but ChintanShah25 has explained that was due to standard analyzer is case sensitive. Now, I am getting data. But, if one match is positive, i am getting whole imageMap instead of single element of matced imageMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wan to get a single element from the `imageMap` array, you need to map `imageMap` as a [`nested` object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) like this:

```
     "imageMap": {
        "type": "nested",             <--- add this
        "properties": {
          "item1": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "item2": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "item3": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
```

Then you need to wipe your index and re-build it from scratch with this new mapping.

In the end, you'll be able to retrieve only a specific element using a [`nested` `inner_hits` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits):

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "query" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "imageMap",
            "query" : {
                "match" : {"imageMap.item2" : "ImageThumbnail_100_By_44"}
            },
            "inner_hits" : {} 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above query is giving me single element in inner hits but also whole imageMap in hits. Is there any way to work filter out this. Thank you very much for previous helps.

Comment: Yes, simply specify `_source: false` on the first line and you're good to go. I've edited my answer.

Comment: yes, it is working as per my expectation. Thank you very much. It helps a lot. Can in a query we can use response of a query.

Comment: Cool, glad to help! To answer your last question, no you cannot use a response of a query in another query, you have to deal with this in your  client code.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not working because you are using `term query` which does not do any `analysis` on your search string. Since you have not specified any analyzer in mapping *ImageThumbnail_100_By_44* is stored as *imagethumbnail_100_by_44* because it is analyzed by [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)

Depending on your requirement you could either map your `item2` as `"index : not_analyzed"` and your query will work fine or you could use `match query` which will do analysis.

```
{
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "imageMap"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "imageMap.item2": {
              "query": "ImageThumbnail_100_By_44"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please go through [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html?q=term%20q) to have better understanding of analysis process